# Business Days Resample with Offset

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to resample daily frequency data to business days using the Pandas [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) function with an offset so the last day of the week becomes Thursday and the beginning Sunday.

This is the code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

resampled_data = df.resample('B', base=-1)
```

But it keeps resampling so Friday is being used in the resample and Sunday is excluded. I tried many different values for `base` and `loffset` but it's not affecting the resampling.

Please note: The raw data is using UTC timestamps. Timezone is Eastern Daylight Time. Sunday UTC 21:00 - Thursday UTC 21:00.

Comment: Can you please show a [mre] that demonstrates how it is not working and what the expected output should be instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CustomBusinessDay()`.  I've resampled the whole of Jan which includes Fri / Sat and also included `day_name()` and `dayofweek` to show it has worked.

```
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2020,1,1), dt.datetime(2020,2,1)))
bd = pd.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(n=1, 
                                          weekmask="Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu")
df = df.resample(rule=bd).first().assign(
    day=lambda dfa: dfa.index.day_name(),
    dn=lambda dfa: dfa.index.dayofweek
    
)
```

**output**

```
                  day  dn
2020-01-01  Wednesday   2
2020-01-02   Thursday   3
2020-01-05     Sunday   6
2020-01-06     Monday   0
2020-01-07    Tuesday   1
2020-01-08  Wednesday   2
2020-01-09   Thursday   3
2020-01-12     Sunday   6
2020-01-13     Monday   0
2020-01-14    Tuesday   1
2020-01-15  Wednesday   2
2020-01-16   Thursday   3
2020-01-19     Sunday   6
2020-01-20     Monday   0
2020-01-21    Tuesday   1
2020-01-22  Wednesday   2
2020-01-23   Thursday   3
2020-01-26     Sunday   6
2020-01-27     Monday   0
2020-01-28    Tuesday   1
2020-01-29  Wednesday   2
2020-01-30   Thursday   3
```

Comment: Rob, thanks for the assistance. How would I use CBD to resample into 3, 6 or 9 business days? Previously I was using '3B' or '6B' as the frequency.

Comment: I'm also using a dictionary to assign the frequency and base adjustment depending on the timeframe. I was hoping there would be a simple solution to this so I could keep the format

freq = {'D': ['B', None], 'H': ['H', 1], 'M': ['T', 20]}

Comment: CBD `n=` parameter I believe does different number of days.  You can also pass additional holidays etc.  Take a look at the docs,  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay.html there is also functionality for CBT as well as CBD

Comment: Awesome, really appreciate the assistance. Will give those suggestions a try and see how it goes.